# What is the rationale for using the genitive "такого" in "что в них такого особенного"?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

> А что в них **такого** **особенного**? = And what's so special about it?

I'm familiar with the use of Genitive in a negative construction:

> Не увидел я в них **ничего такого особенного**.
>
> or: **Ничего такого особенного** в них нет.

I wonder why you need Genitive in this interrogative sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is of a phraseological sort, where the components have got individual  idiomatic relationship, which doesn't correspond to usual rules. The sentence starts with a question word after which you can find either **a noun** (толк, прок, польза, радость,  выгода), **a quality adjective** (like in our case), or the pronoun "**такой**". All **in the genitive**

> Что толку?(what's the use?). Что нового?(What's new?) Что такого?(What's of that?)

Such questions or exclamations are often rhetorical or asking about some quality or situation in general. They can be emphasized by particles. More examples

> Что пользы спорить? Что же здесь особенного?Да что же тут такого? Ну что в тебе испанского? Что же тут обидного? Ну что новенького в городе, что интересного?

Answer (score 0):

We got a bunch of cases and use them to express shades of meaning. Genitive is used for direct object instead of accusative in some situations. This is just one of them.

Perhaps it originates from **Что в них есть из особенного?** - *What it has from the list of unusual qualities?*

And **из** like **of** is an indicator of genitive.

By the way people colloquially often say something like **Что тебе купить из одежды?** - *What clothes do you want me to buy?*